# A C++ WinAPI program for changing the process priority classes via PIDs

Tags: c++, console, winapi

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278042/a-c-winapi-program-for-changing-the-process-priority-classes-via-pids-take-2/278054#278054) .)

I have this program (call it, for example, `prioset.exe`), that asks for two command line arguments: (1) the target process PID, (2) a priority class selector in the range `0...5` (as specified in the [WinAPI docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getpriorityclass), where 0 stands for idle priority class, and 5 for real-time priority class.

My main concern is whether we can pass to `dwDesiredAccess` of `OpenProcess` more restricted flags than `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`.

Here's the code:

````
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::wcout;
using std::wcerr;
using std::wstringstream;

static void MyPrintHelp();
static void MyAttemptToChangeProcessPriorityClass(DWORD pid, 
                                                  DWORD priorityClass);

static bool MyCheckPriorityClassSelection(DWORD priorityClassSelection);
static DWORD MyConvertPriorityClassSelectionToFlag(DWORD priorityClassSelection);

int wmain(int argc, const wchar_t** args) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        MyPrintHelp();
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD pid;
    DWORD priorityClassSelection;

    wstringstream wss;
    wss << args[1] << L" " << args[2];
    wss >> pid;

    if (wss.fail() || wss.eof()) {
        wcerr << L"Error: bad PID (" << args[1] << L"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    wss >> priorityClassSelection;

    if (wss.fail()) {
        wcerr << L"Error: bad priority class selector (" << args[2] << L")\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!MyCheckPriorityClassSelection(priorityClassSelection)) {
        wcerr << L"Error: bad priority class selection: " 
              << priorityClassSelection
              << L". Must be between 0 and 5, inclusively.\n";

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    MyAttemptToChangeProcessPriorityClass(
        pid,
        MyConvertPriorityClassSelectionToFlag(
            priorityClassSelection));
}

static void MyPrintHelp() {
    wcout << L"prioset.exe PID PRIORITY\n";
}

static std::wstring GetLastErrorAsString(DWORD errorMessageId)
{
    LPWSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;

    size_t size = FormatMessage(
                        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
                        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
                        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, 
        errorMessageId, 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
        (LPWSTR) &messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    //Copy the error message into a std::string.
    std::wstring message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the Win32's string's buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);
    return message;
}

static void MyAttemptToChangeProcessPriorityClass(DWORD pid, DWORD priorityClass) {
    HANDLE processHandle = 
        ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 
            false, 
            pid);

    if (processHandle == NULL) {
        wcout << L"Error: could not open a process with PID " << pid << "\n";
        return;
    }

    DWORD oldPriorityClass = GetPriorityClass(processHandle);

    if (oldPriorityClass == 0) {
        DWORD errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        wcerr << L"Error: " 
              << GetLastErrorAsString(errorCode) 
              << L"Error code: " 
              << errorCode 
              << L"\n";

        ::CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    if (!::SetPriorityClass(processHandle, priorityClass)) {
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        wcerr << L"Error: "
            << GetLastErrorAsString(errorCode)
            << L"Error code: "
            << errorCode
            << L"\n";

        ::CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    DWORD newPriorityClass = GetPriorityClass(processHandle);

    if (newPriorityClass == 0) {
        DWORD errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        wcerr << L"Error: "
            << GetLastErrorAsString(errorCode)
            << L"Error code: "
            << errorCode
            << L"\n";

        ::CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    ::CloseHandle(processHandle);

    if (newPriorityClass == priorityClass) {
        wcout << L"Successfully changed the priority class from "
              << oldPriorityClass 
              << L" to "
              << newPriorityClass
              << L"\n";
    } else {
        wcout << L"Could not change the priority class from "
              << oldPriorityClass 
              << L" to "
              << priorityClass
              << L" Instead, "
              << newPriorityClass
              << L" is used as a new priority class.\n";
    }
}

static bool MyCheckPriorityClassSelection(DWORD priorityClassSelection) {
    return priorityClassSelection >= 0 || priorityClassSelection < 6;
}

static DWORD MyConvertPriorityClassSelectionToFlag(
    DWORD priorityClassSelection) {
    switch (priorityClassSelection) {
        case 0:
            return IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS;

         case 1:
            return BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

         case 2:
            return NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

         case 3:
            return ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

         case 4:
            return HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS;

         case 5:
            return REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS;

         default:
            throw L"Bad priority class selection.";
    }
}

```
````

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but from the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights) I would assume that PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION (or PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION)   PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION is sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR Just checked it. Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some remarks.

The error reporting is not consistent:

- Most error messages go to standard error (which is good), but some go to standard output.
- Most invalid input causes the program to exit with `EXIT_FAILURE` (which is good), but failures in `MyAttemptToChangeProcessPriorityClass()` make the program terminate normally.
- An error in the integer to priority conversion throws a C++ exception.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights) it suffices to call `OpenProcess()` with

```
PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION
```

You have two separate functions `MyCheckPriorityClassSelection()` which checks the range of the (integer) input, and `MyConvertPriorityClassSelectionToFlag()` which converts that integer to a priority value. That bears a risk if additional priorities are introduced.

I would combine that into a single function which returns a priority value or indicates an error.